# Mount NoSQL DB as File System

Tags: nosql, filesystems, couchdb, mount, riak

I am looking for the way to easily mount one of the NoSQL DB as File System both in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS or CentOs 5

I know there are there are some fuse projects for mongoDB, CouchDB, riak,

But I can't make them compiled nicely and work fine. Do you have a stable and running a File System on them?

I think Riak is the best over them. As it is truly distributed like Cassandra.
But I think using BigCouch with Couch-fuse may also work.
I just can't make that work fine in my system.

Any easy to install version?

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak for CouchDB. (as I'm not familiar with the others)

[UbuntuOne](https://one.ubuntu.com/) is a file-sync system (much like Dropbox) that uses CouchDB on the back-end. It's closed-source, but I'm mostly pointing it out as proof-of-concept.

In addition, there is a project out there called [couchdb-fuse](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-fuse/), which mounts CouchDB design doc attachments as part of the filesystem.

Comment: To my knowledge, file sync in Ubuntu One is not handled by CouchDB. There is an independent file sync daemon. (It's possible metadata about the files is in couch).

Answer (score 0):

This question [FS based on a database without using fuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222432/fs-based-on-a-database-without-using-fuse) has some good advice other than just the discussion about mongodb.